Can not install MediaWiki extension PageForms
I have MediaWiki version 1.41 and want to Install https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms. I followed the download instruction from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms/Download_and_installation and executed:
 git clone https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/mediawiki/extensions/PageForms.git

Which results in the webbrowser to the following error message:

I changed the extension name from 'Mediawiki_PageForms' to 'PageForms' but without any difference.
What can be the reason for this error and how to resolve it?

You may want to check whether the file extension.json is really present at the long path from the error message. If it is, check its (and the directory PageForms's) owner and permissions. Perhaps, the php-fpm or Apache process cannot read it. Use some working extension's files as reference.

I might do so, but that is a tricky path. The installation procedures and files should be complete. And I am working in a simple shared hosting environment, where can not change file's permissions. But even if I had, then I have to dig into and extension which I did not build. The change I make a mistake and go a wrong direction is much larger, then for the person (s) who wrote the extension. Other MediaWiki extensions worked as described.
